# jQuery animation doesn't work for my navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation menu on top of my page made out of list items. I want to apply jQuery code to make the list items to slide down one by one when my page loads...Can't get it work.

index.html

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>      
      <a href="#"><li id="goFirst">Projects</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li id="goSecond">Contact</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li id="goThird">Blog</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#goFirst').animate({top: '+=75px'}, 1000);
    $('#goSecond').delay(1000).animate({top: '+=75px'}, 1000);
    $('#goThird').delay(2000).animate({top: '+=75px'}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `marginTop` instead of `top`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#goFirst').animate({
    marginTop: '+=75px'
  }, 1000);
  $('#goSecond').delay(1000).animate({
    marginTop: '+=75px'
  }, 1000);
  $('#goThird').delay(2000).animate({
    marginTop: '+=75px'
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li id="goFirst">
      <a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li id="goSecond">
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li id="goThird">
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just set `position: relative` on the `li`s in CSS. But don't EVER put anything other than `<li>`s directly inside an `<ul>`...

Comment: @blex yeah `position` is an option here too. It really depends on how you want the rest of the page to behave when you animate. Also, I edited to make it valid HTML.